# Magento 2 - Connecting to Remote Production Instance and Getting/Setting Entities

Tags: magento2, api

I was wondering if there was a way to have a local instance of **Magento 2** connect to a remote instance, and get and/or set entities - outside of using the **API**?

The reason I am asking is because I am trying to create a data bridge. My local instance has access to an internal database which runs the company's RMS. The local instance can connect to the production database via an SSH tunnel.

The concept would allow the switching of the connection to either populate the development or production environments.

I am relatively new to Magento 2 and did not know if this was feasible, outside of using the API?

Thank you so much for your insight and expertise.

Have a wonderful and blessed day!